# Login to VM recreated locally from Azure VHD not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, azure

how can I login to virtual machine recreated locally from VHD downloaded from Azure? My SSH credentials are not working.

Thanks for your help.

Carlo

Answer (score 0):

It was keyboard issue. Some special characters were not entered correctly in password.